# Extrude from the vertices

Tags: vertices, extrude

I tried searching this online, but didn't know what it was called, so had some hard time finding anything related.

Just wondering if anyone know how I can turn a flat surface, where the edge and vertices are linked, and extrude it from all sides from the vertices to give me something like below?

Thanks.

[image: original flat surface with vertices]

[image: Extrude from all sides from the vertices]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144828/is-it-possible-to-split-a-vertex/144831#144831

Answer (score 3):

You can create this shape relatively easily using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to *Bevel Vertices* with 2 segments:

[image]